# replacing a string in file after doing some changes to it

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

**The task:**

I got a file with subtitles where the times are awfully off. All by the same amount of time though. I want to run a script on them to add / subtract a certain amount of time. I'm trying to do this via command line in linux. So I'm trying to use awk and / or sed. I got no experience with them, though.

The strings I want to alter look like this: 01:35:12,300

**The problem:**

Using awk I managed to write a script file, that  I can invoke like this:

```
awk -f subtitles_shift.awk change="-01:00:11" subtitle_sample
```

What my script basically does, is: It converts the strings in the file, as well as the one passed as an argument into seconds. Makes the changes, converts back to a string and then spits the whole thing out again. And it works.

The only thing, though, is, that I got no clue now, how to write these changes back to the file ...

**What I thinK:**

I think, I should use sed for the job, as it allows me to write back to a file. But with sed I don't know how to write such a script that does calculations on a search string before applying the replacement string.

```
sed 's/..:..:..,.../REPLACEMENT/' <old >new
```

How can I make all these necessary calculations on the matched pattern, before giving sed back the replacement string?

I hope You understand, what I mean ...

**Last but not least:**

Thanks a lot in advance!

**code examples -- code examples**

This is the main part of my awk script:

```
# looking for the lines that hold the time strings
/^..:/ {
    # picking the first and third column. These are the times
    start = $1; 
    end   = $3;
    # calculating changes by invoking functions
    start_new = alter_time(start, change, sign);
    end_new   = alter_time(end, change, sign);
}
```

**possible solution**

Hell, yeah! I can just process everything, do the math on the necessary lines, and write all the lines back to a file. This seems to work so far:

```
{
    if ($1 ~ /^..:/) {

        start = $1;
        end   = $3;

        start_new = alter_time(start, change, sign);
        end_new   = alter_time(end, change, sign);

        print start_new " --> " end_new > "times.srt";
    } else {
        print $0 > "times.srt";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but if you have more operations on the file, you can put these in a file ("myfile.sed"), and invoke sed with `sed -f myfile.sed <old >new`

Comment: My problem is, that in my awk script I use functions and stuff to calculate the changes. I simply cannot find explanation on how to do that with sed. Then again: Would sed be the right tool to do this job?! PLease, tell me if I should post details of my script.

Comment: There are no true functions in sed, but if the task is not too hard, you could emulate them by using {} blocks and branching. It will get complex very soon. Sed does have the advantage of not assuming the lines to exist of fields separated by FS; the objects of its operations are basically lines, not fields.

Comment: You can run your `awk` script and then redirect the output to a new file e.g. `awk ... > tmp` and then `mv tmp origfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possibly far from perfect. but that's the script I came up with so far. and, hey, it does it's job ;-)

my first awk script, btw, so please bear with me, but feel free to point out all the weaknesses ...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# invoke me like this:
#
# [awk -f] subtitles_shift.awk var="-01:42:09" file.srt
#
# @ var     the shift forward or backward
# @ file    the srt file to be processed
#
# fractions of seconds are ignored. the script gives the 
# following format back:
# HH:MM:SS,000 --> HH:MM:SS,000
# 
# the script saves to a file named times.srt in the
# current directory.

#############################################
# BEGIN
#############################################

BEGIN {
    print "\nstarting script (subtitles_shift.awk):";
    # get the first variable passed
    var = ARGV[1];
    # assign only the value
    split(var, a, "=");
    change = a[2];
    # assign the operation (addition or subtraction)
    sign = check_sign(change);
    # trim a possible sign from the variable
    sub(/^[^0-9]/, "", change);
    print "the time shift will be: " , sign change;
    print "--------------------------------------";
}

function convert_time_string_to_sec(string) 
{
    # string should be of the format 00:00:00,0[00]
    split(string, a, ":");
    split(a[3], b, ",");
    hh = a[1];
    mm = a[2];
    ss = b[1];
    # calculate the total time in seconds
    return ( hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss );
}

function add_leading_zero(str)
{
    if (length(str) == 1) {
        str = ( "0" str );
    }
    return str;
}

function trim_fraction(str)
{
    split(str, array, ".");
    return array[1];
}

function convert_sec_to_string(sec)
{
    # get hours as a fraction
    hours  = sec / 3600;
    # only take complete hours
    h  = trim_fraction(hours);
    # add a leading zero (if necessary)
    hh = add_leading_zero(h);
    # subtract full hours from sec
    sec -= ( h * 3600 );
    # get minutes as a fraction
    min  = sec / 60;
    # only take complete minutes
    m  = trim_fraction(min);
    # add a leading zero (if necessary)
    mm = add_leading_zero(m);
    # subtract full minutes from sec
    sec -= ( m * 60 );
    # add a leading zero (if necessary)
    ss = add_leading_zero(sec);
    # prepare full string and return it
    string = ( hh ":" mm ":" ss ",000" );
    return string;
}

function alter_time(time_str, alter_str, sign)
{
    # get time in seconds
    sec = convert_time_string_to_sec(time_str);
    dif = convert_time_string_to_sec(alter_str);
    # add or subtract according to sign
    if (sign == "+") {
        new = sec + dif;
    } else {
        new = sec - dif;
    }
    # convert back to a string (00:00:00,000) and return
    newstr = convert_sec_to_string(new);
    return newstr;
}

function check_sign(str)
{
    # check for a sign, if none assume addition
    first  = substr(str, 0, 1);
    if (first == "-")
        return "-";
    else
        return "+";
}

#############################################
# main block
#############################################

{
    # if the line starts with time string
    if ($1 ~ /^..:/) {
        # assign start and end time
        start = $1;
        end   = $3;
        # run the main function to change according to argument passed
        start_new = alter_time(start, change, sign);
        end_new   = alter_time(end, change, sign);
        # print the new line to file (string --> string)
        print start_new " --> " end_new > "times.srt";
    } else {
        line = $0;
        # trim line feeds (appeared on my linux machine ^M at eol)
        gsub(/[:\015]/, "", line);
        # print the line to file
        print line > "times.srt";
    }
}

#############################################
# END
#############################################

END {
    print "file times.srt created.";
    print "--------------------------------------";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use in-place subtraction, meaning, get the subtitle file, and parse till you reach a time format, using awk, (ad you've done)

then use [time function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) of awk language, to subtract and replace on the spot.

or, you can use something like this for subtraction, (thanks to [glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman))

```
awk -v 'time=16:13:04,699' -v "date=$(date +%H:%M:%S)" '
  function abs(x) {return x<0 ? -x : x}
  BEGIN {
    split(time, ary, /[:,]/); t_sec = 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3]
    split(date, ary, /:/);    d_sec = 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3]
    # output difference in minutes
    print abs(t_sec - d_sec)/60
  }
'
```

I don't think you'd need sed for this, anyway, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did it with my own set of functions, though ... Might not be as elegant, but does it's job fine! Tried mktime, but it gets confusing adding and subtracting two dates.